# Threading: Dynamic GUI Refresh and Speed issue with PyQt4

Tags: multithreading, pyqt

The playThread emits signals to movePhead() to move the play head. This is updated smoothly until a DynamicThread is needed, which needs to do a lot of processing while playback proceeds, such as move and create objects in the GUI.

Two things happen when a DynamicThread is created:

1. Playback slows down intermittently, while it is processing
2. After DynamicThread is finished processing, the screen ceases to update 
   automatically, updating only when scrolled off then back on.

I have tried the following at various points in each process with no results:

- app.processEvents(), update(), and repaint()
- removing all calls to data structures in main window by making them
  global in DynamicThread's run() function

I am new to threading, so maybe there is a simple structural problem.

Please let me know what I could be missing.

I am using an open source sequencer template: https://github.com/rhetr/seq-gui

```
def movePhead(x):
    playHead.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(x, 0))
    y = main.view.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition() + 125

    main.view.centerOn(x, y)

class DynamicThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5):
        super(DynamiteThread , self).__init__()
        self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")
        self.v1, self.v2, self.v3, self.v4, self.v5 = v1, v2, v3, v4, v5
        self.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()

    def run(self):
        self.process(self.v1, self.v2, self.v3, self.v4, self.v5)
        self.stop()

class PlayThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayThread , self).__init__()
        self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()

    def run(self):
        global xLocToNoteItems
        global xLocToRhythms
        global currentLLindex

        for xloc in xrange(currentLLindex + 1, len(orderedXlocations)):
            currentLLindex = xloc
            for noteItem in xLocToNoteItems[orderedXlocations[xloc]]:
                player.note_on(noteItem.note[0], noteItem.note[3], 1)

            self.emit(self.signal, orderedXlocations[xloc] - 31.5)

            offtime = xLocToRhythms[orderedXlocations[xloc]]
            time.sleep(offtime / 2.0)

            for noteItem in xLocToNoteItems[orderedXlocations[xloc]]:
                player.note_off(noteItem.note[0], noteItem.note[3], 1)
```

Comment: Delving further into this issue has been put on hold. I was using the GUI in a Windows XP virtual machine. I've since been able to get PyQt4 installed on my mac (10.5.8), but this caused issues with PyGame. I may test further if/when I integrate a different MIDI output mechanism

Comment: Note that using multiple threads in Python can decrease performance considerably. Look into multiprocessing as well